# Book for advanced homological algebra

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra

I already read the books:

1.- An introduction to homological algebra - Rotman (the two versions of it)

2.- An introduction to homological algebra - Weibel

3.- A course on homological algebra - Hilton & Stambach

4.- Homological algebra - Cartan & Eilenberg

5.- Homology - Maclane

I'm looking for a book on advanced homological algebra. Can anyone recommend me one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gelfand and manin methods of homological algebra.
I doubt that you read those books from cover to cover.

Comment: Of course not, I skip some proofs and some exercises. But I can ensure, 95% of Rotman's, Weibel and Hilton-Stambach, 85%-90% of Cartan-Eilenber and Maclane. Thanks, I'll look at Gelfand and Mannin's book.